# Calculating two integers fields in django

Tags: django

I want to calculate these fields and want output for example  (budget - Expense)
(budget + Expense) (budget * Expense).
how could i do that.

```
 Class calculate(models.Model):
       budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       Expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) your queryset. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F

Calculate.objects.annotate(
    difference=F('budget') - F('expense'),
    total=F('budget') + F('expense'),
    product=F('budget') * F('expense')
)
```

The `Calculate` objects that arise from this will have three extra attributes: `.difference`, `.total` and `.product` that contain the difference, sum and product of `budget` and `expense` respectively.

> **Note**: The name of Django models is formatted as `CamelCase`, so `Calculate`, instead of <s>`calculate`</s>. The attributes are formatted `lowercase_with_underscore`, so `expense` instead of <s>`Expense`</s>.

Comment: Thanks let me try.

Comment: <QuerySet [<Add: Add object (1)>]>  bro i am getting this thing while displaying on html page not getting answer like 100 - 50  budget - expense..

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: that makes perfect sense, since you here obtain all the `Calculate` objects, you thus need to iterate over it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use model method.

```
Class calculate(models.Model):
       budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       Expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)

       def get_budget_total(self):
           return budget + Expenses
```

use like model function

```
claculate_object.get_budget_total()
```

and in template file use direct

```
claculate_object.get_budget_total
```

FYI use correct naming conventions for naming method and class name 
for class names use capitalized and for methods and properties use small case

Comment: Thanks ajay .. Then how i will display on html page.                                                     
   should i use this  code inside views.py                       claculate_object.get_budget_total

Comment: in python file use this as  claculate_object.get_budget_total() and in template file use direct claculate_object.get_budget_total without function syntex

Comment: Your welcome.
And if you found this answer helpful, then i think it desurve a thumbs up